# Windows Community Toolkit Twitter service - get full timeline

Tags: c#, twitter, uwp, windows-community-toolkit

How to get the timeline of all people, which I currently follow? I see in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/services/twitter) only the way to get the timeline of single person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is this endpoint:

> GET statuses/home_timeline

See Twitter API [documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-home_timeline.html).

This endpoint is already implemented in the `TwitterDataProvider` in [this](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/d2ae6ad35a22a7915ca20d9c6f0d5d5b0e75895a/Microsoft.Toolkit.Services/Services/Twitter/TwitterDataProvider.cs#L543) method and that can be called via `RequestAsync<T>` on Twitter Service.

```
var config = new TwitterDataConfig() { QueryType = TwitterQueryType.Home, Query = "" };
var timeline = await twitterService.RequestAsync<Tweet>( config );
```